# Google Remarketing Network List 300+ per day Google Remarketing impressions 10 per month?

Tags: google-ads-api

We have set up Google Remarketing Tag with Google Tag Manager.

In *Adwords* it shows that our audience is `300+` per day yet we only had 10 impressions in March and 0 in February.

What could we be doing wrong for the ads to not be showing to those **300+ visitors**?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a 3d-party advertizing service, not programming.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That means you are going way too heavy on the target layering. For example, don't use Interests, Topics, Age and Gender altogether.

Test it out and see for yourself, create an Adgroup with just Interests + Age, and then create the same ad group but target to Gender + Topics. You'll see improvement in impressions.

Basically, don't layer too much or the size of your audience shrinks drastically.